# how would I show the original Form2 from inside Form1 when I press button on Form1 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, show

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2.Show();
    }
```

I have the code above which in my opinion contains no error but it won't execute by some reason.
It says the error "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property" but what I have missed?
I have just two forms (Form1 and Form2) and one button nothing more. I used a registry cleaner but the error persists.
There exists another code for it which worked, but this code makes a copy of my form as a new variable, but I would like to show the original form like it Visual Basic did.

Comment: `(new Form2()).Show();`

Comment: You'll have to unlearn some bad habits you picked up from vb.net.  Like this one, you cannot call an instance method like Show() without providing a reference to the object.  VB.NET unfortunately allowed this in the specific case of the Form class, giving VB6 programmers a shot at writing Winforms code.  That's over and done with in C#, you'll have to use the *new* operator to create a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to storing a reference to your Form at Class level, you need to check if it has been closed since the last time it was used.  In that case you'd need to create a new instance (just as you do for the very first use).  The below example also restores the form if it was minimized:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Form2 F2 = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (F2 == null || F2.IsDisposed)
        {
            F2 = new Form2();
            F2.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            if (F2.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                F2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
            F2.Activate();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form2 or Form1 are just a names of classes. Before using of this classes you need to create an instance of them

```
Form2 secondaryForm = new Form2();
```

After this you can use all methods and properties of that class `secondaryForm.Show();`

So before using/showing your Form2, you need to create an instance. If you want show

> your original form

, meens that instance are already created. You need check your code where that instance was created and put reference to that form in variable:

Create a variable in Form1:

```
private Form2 secondaryForm;
```

In code where you created already your original Form2 just use this variable:

```
this.secondaryForm = new Form2();
```

After this anywhere in Form1's code you can show a Form2 with next line:

```
this.secondaryFomr.Show();
```